# VPN on Windows not working for some domains

Tags: networking, windows-10, google-chrome, vpn

I have setup a VPN on Windows 10. I am able to access some domains via the VPN, but other domains seem to be going via the internet connection. I have two questions:

- how can I verify which interface is being used for a particular domain? Connections are initiated on the browser (Chrome)
- how can I specify that some domains (let's say all `*.info` domains) should use the VPN instead of using the Internet. Appart from this, I do not want to apply any other changes to the VPN configuration, since it is otherwise working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may use for that the
[tracert command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows).

Below are two tracert examples, where the second one is via a VPN.
The difference can be seen from the first hop :

[image]